# トランザクションによる処理について

Tags: vue.js, firebase

#### トランザクションを使い、2つの処理を実行したい

現在、VUE、firestoreを用いて仮想的な投げ銭アプリを作成しています。
500円持っているログインユーザーが、指定した相手に送金ボタンを押すと、ログインユーザーの持ち金が減り、指定ユーザーの持ち金が増えるシステムを組みたいです。
トランザクション処理初めて書くので、悪戦苦闘しながら書いていたのですが、うまく実装までたどり着かなかったため、お力添えを頂きたく質問させていただきました。
初学者のため、コードの記述がおかしいところが多々あるかもしれませんが、ご指摘、アドバイスいただけると幸いです。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
FirebaseError: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```js
Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    user: {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
      myWallet: '',
      uid: ''
    },
    userData: [],
    inputValue: ''
  },
  getters: {
    email(state) {
      return state.user.email;
    },
    password(state) {
      return state.user.password;
    },
    name(state) {
      return state.user.name;
    },
    myWallet(state) {
      return state.user.myWallet;
    },
    uid(state) {
      return state.user.uid;
    },
    userData(state) {
      return state.userData
    },
    inputValue(state) {
      return state.inputValue
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    
    updateDestinationBalance(state,docs){
      state.uid = docs[0].id
    },
    updateMyBalance(state){
      state.user.myWallet = Number
    }
   
  },
  actions: {
    async closeModal2({ state,commit }, inputValue) {
      const db = firebase.firestore();
      const isMyUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
      try {
        const receiverDocs = await db.collection('userData').where('uid', '==', state.uid).get()
        const receiverId = receiverDocs.docs[0].id
        const senderDocs = await db.collection('userData').where('uid', '==', isMyUid).get()
        const senderId = senderDocs.docs[0].id
        await db.runTransaction(async t => {
          //送金される側
          await t.update(db.collection('userData').doc(receiverId), {
            myWallet: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(Number(inputValue))
          })
          commit('updateDestinationBalance', inputValue)
          //送金する側
          await t.update(db.collection('userData').doc(senderId), {
            myWallet: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-Number(inputValue))
          })
          commit('updateMyBalance', inputValue)
        })
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
  },
 
})
```

```
<template>
  <div class="overlay" v-show="showContent2">
    <div class="main-content">
      <p>あなたの残高 {{ val.myWallet }}</p>
      <p>送る金額</p>
      <input v-model="inputValue" type="number" />

      <div class="button-content">
        <p>
          <button @click="closeModal2" class="modal-button">送信</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>



<script>
export default {
  props: {
    val: {
      type: null,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showContent2: false,
      userData: [],
      inputValue:'',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    openModal2() {
      this.$emit("open", this.showContent2);
    },
    closeModal2() {
      this.$emit("close", this.showContent2);
      this.$store.dispatch("closeModal2", {
        inputValue:this.inputValue
    });
    },
  },
 
  
};
</script>
```

どのようにコード書き換えればいいか、ご教授いただきたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/358332) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: エラーメッセージから推測すると `state.userData` の要素に `uid` が設定されていない `state.user` データが存在しているのではないでしょうか。参考記事: [Handling undefined Values with Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42310950/handling-undefined-values-with-firebase)

Comment: uidが設定されてないstate.userが存在している場合の解決法はどのようなものがあるのでしょうか